# download images - python

Tags: python, image

I tried to write code with some youtube tutorial, and all code is the same

```
import urllib.request

def dl_jpg(url, file_path, file_name):
    full_path = file_path + file_name + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

url = input("Enter img URL to download:")
file_name = input("Enter file name to save as:")

dl_jpg(url, "images/", file_name)
```

But when I run it and call full names as test I get error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'images/test.jpg'
```

And I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: I don't know how that error message can be any clearer....

Comment: You don't have images directory or test.jpg. Try giving absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need the folder "Images" created before executing the code.
Your code won't create the folder if it doesn't exists, that's the problem.

With the [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) you can check and create/remove folders (if you want to do it at run-time)

Comment: Thank you. I used os module as you suggested and it works now.

import urllib.request
import os

def dl_jpg(url, file_path, file_name):
    full_path = file_path + file_name + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

url = input("Enter img URL to download:")
file_name = input("Enter file name to save as:")

os.mkdir("images")

dl_jpg(url, "images/", file_name)

Answer (score 1):

Try this please. I have added a function to create a folder named `images`.

```
import urllib.request

def dl_jpg(url, file_path, file_name):
    full_path = file_path + file_name + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

url = input("Enter img URL to download:")
file_name = input("Enter file name to save as:")

def _new_folder(dir_name):
    if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
        os.makedirs(dir_name)
    return

_new_folder(images)

dl_jpg(url, "images/", file_name)
```